# JQM Loading in the same page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, text, load, loading

I have one problem..
I have one page like this:

```
 <div data-role="content">


    <div id="loadingSchedaAuto" ></div> 

        <div id="datiAuto" style="display:none">

            <img src=""  class="imgPrincipale" alt="" width="100%" height="auto" style="padding:2px; border:1px solid #000;"  />

            <p class="nome" align="center"></p>

            <ul style="padding: 5px; " data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="a" >

            <li data-role="list-divider">Dati generali</li>
            <li>
                <strong>Prezzo</strong>: <span class="prezzo" style="color:#E30025; font-weight: bold;"></span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <strong>Alimentazione</strong>: <span class="alimentazione"></span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <strong>Cilindrata</strong>: <span class="cilindrata"></span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <strong>Potenza</strong>: <span class="potenza"></span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <strong>Colore</strong>: <span class="colore"></span>
            </li>

            <li id="immatricolazione" > <!-- id aggiunto per poter inserire una li degli interni dopo immatricolazione -->
                <strong>Immatricolazione</strong>: <span class="immatricolazione"></span>
            </li>

            <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-r" data-expanded-icon="arrow-d">
                <h3>Cambio</h3>
                <ul data-role="listview">
                <li>
                <span class="cambio"></span>
                </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-r" data-expanded-icon="arrow-d" id="equipaggiamento">
                <h3>Equipaggiamento</h3>
                <ul class="equip" data-role="listview" data-mini="true"></ul>
            </div>
        </ul>



    </div>

</div>
```

the div with id=datiAuto is dinamic, and i need to show loading message every time before that it's loaded.

i made this functions:

```
      function showLoading(loading, scheda) {
 alert("load pagina");
 $(loading).show();
 $(scheda).hide();


};

function showSchedaAuto(loading, scheda) {

    $(loading).remove();
    alert("pagina caricata");
     $(scheda).show();


    };
```

and i call this function here:

```
 $(document).delegate("#scheda-auto", "pageshow", function() {

    showLoading("#loadingSchedaAuto", "#datiAuto"); 

    $("#scheda-auto").load("scheda.html #datiAuto", function() {

        showSchedaAuto("#loadingSchedaAuto", "#datiAuto");
    });..................
```

this Works once, but the second time i try to show the Div, the page is blank!!

anyone can help me?

Thanks!
David

Comment: Which versions of jQuery and jQuery Mobile are you using?

Comment: 1.9.1 jquery and 1.3.0 jquery mobile

Answer (score 0):

May be the jquery version is creating this issue here if you are saying that code is working fine but once so try using `.on()` instead of `.delegate()`.

Hope this code works for you:

```
$(document).on("pageshow","#scheda-auto", function() {

   .......
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for post! it doesn't work, if i use .on(), the div is always hide!

Comment: The alert of the functions, always works!just the page is blank!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies here

```
function showSchedaAuto(loading, scheda) {

    $(loading).remove(); 
    alert("pagina caricata");
    $(scheda).show();
```

};

`$(loading).remove();`  // you are removing the element from DOM, probably you want to hide it

Also use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), .delgate() is deprecated. Syntax for `on()` is bit different from delegate.

Comment: yes, was hide, but it's the same, the element that i remove here is the loader, not the DIV! the loader is show every time but the div is hide!

Comment: @user2527017 can you create a jsfiddle for this program? It will help us in debugging the problem